# Is it possible to combine mapAreas from ArcGISOnline in one offline map on android?

Tags: arcgis, esri, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-android-api

I try to create an offline map using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 100.5.0. I follow preplanned workflow according the guide https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/guide/take-map-offline-preplanned.htm. I create mapAreas in ArcGISOnline and try to download them from device. I want to get an offline map, which contains all mapAreas together like in app maps.me(on a big map you have downloaded regions with deeper detailing), but instead I am getting an offline map made from last downloaded area. So I created mapArea "Europe" with scale world - cities and mapArea "Berlin" with scale cities - buildings (both basemaps - openstreetmaps, no feature layers) and downloaded them successfully, see 2 tpk files in a folder, but mobile_map.mmpk and package.info files only contain data related to last loaded area. Is it possible at all to get what I want, combine tpk files in one map?

My code in Kotlin:

```
        val portal = Portal("https://www.arcgis.com/", false)
        val portalItem = PortalItem(portal, itemID)
        val offlineMapTask = OfflineMapTask(portalItem)
        //get all of the preplanned map areas in the web map
        val mapAreasFuture = offlineMapTask.preplannedMapAreasAsync
        mapAreasFuture.addDoneListener {
            try {
                // get the list of areas
                val mapAreas = mapAreasFuture.get()
                val directory = getDirectory()
                prepareDir(directory)
                // loop through the map areas
                var i = 0
                for (mapArea in mapAreas) {
                    mapArea.loadAsync()
                    mapArea.addDoneLoadingListener {
                        val downloadJob = offlineMapTask.downloadPreplannedOfflineMap(mapArea, directory)
                        downloadJob.start()

                        downloadJob.addJobDoneListener {
                            i++
                            if (i == mapAreas.size) {
                                val offlineMapPackage = MobileMapPackage(path)


                             offlineMapPackage.addDoneLoadingListener({
                               if (offlineMapPackage.getLoadStatus() === LoadStatus.LOADED) {

                                   val mobileMap = offlineMapPackage.getMaps().get(0)

                                   myCompletionFuncToShowMap(mobileMap)
                               } else {
                                   println("PACKAGING FAILED")
                               }
                             })
                             offlineMapPackage.loadAsync()
                           }
                        }

                    }

                }

            } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I duplicated the question on community.esri.com and got an answer, thanks to Luke Smallwood from esri. So, yes, it is possible. The "Europe" map area has to be added as basemap layer if I set mapView.map to Berlin and also every map area has to be saved in its own directory.
Downloading areas:

```
val portal = Portal("https://www.arcgis.com/", false)
val portalItem = PortalItem(portal, itemID)
val offlineMapTask = OfflineMapTask(portalItem)
//get all of the preplanned map areas in the web map
val mapAreasFuture = offlineMapTask.preplannedMapAreasAsync
mapAreasFuture.addDoneListener {
    try {
        // get the list of areas
        val mapAreas = mapAreasFuture.get()
        val directory = getDirectory() //my function returns String path

        // loop through the map areas
        for (mapArea in mapAreas) {
            mapArea.loadAsync()
            mapArea.addDoneLoadingListener {
                val downloadJob = offlineMapTask.downloadPreplannedOfflineMap(mapArea, directory + "/" + mapArea.portalItem.title)
                downloadJob.start()
                downloadJob.addJobDoneListener {
                    val offlineMapPackage = MobileMapPackage(directory + "/" + mapArea.portalItem.title)
                    offlineMapPackage.addDoneLoadingListener({
                        if (offlineMapPackage.getLoadStatus() != LoadStatus.LOADED) {
                            println("PACKAGING FAILED")
                        }
                    })
                    offlineMapPackage.loadAsync()
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

Files after downloading:

```
.../files/maps/Berlin/p13/129294b8-3a70-4d79-a421-24ff14cb19fc.tpk
.../files/maps/Berlin/p13/mobile_map.mmap
.../files/maps/Berlin/package.info
.../files/maps/Europa/p13/2547a985-c98f-49be-a187-5ae3b7a9da09.tpk
.../files/maps/Europa/p13/mobile_map.mmap
.../files/maps/Europa/package.info
```

Displaying an offline map:

```
val path = getDirectory() + "/Berlin"
val offlineMapPackage = MobileMapPackage(path)
offlineMapPackage.addDoneLoadingListener {
    if (offlineMapPackage.getLoadStatus() == LoadStatus.LOADED && !offlineMapPackage.getMaps().isEmpty()) {
        mapView.map = offlineMapPackage.getMaps().get(0)
        val cache = TileCache(getDirectory() + "/Europa/p13/2547a985-c98f-49be-a187-5ae3b7a9da09.tpk")
        val layer = ArcGISTiledLayer(cache)
        mapView.map.basemap.baseLayers.add(layer)
        mapView.map.minScale = 1.8489297737236E7
        mapView.map.maxScale = 2256.994353
    } else {
        println("NO MAP FILES")
    }
}
offlineMapPackage.loadAsync()
```

It is important to adjust mapView.map.minScale to include Europe levels, otherwise on device the map only allows to scale between Berlin levels. The scale levels are listed here https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/web-map-zoom-levels-updated/ .